# alertDialog.show doesn`t work in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

alertDiaolg doesn`t work in fragment error in builder.show() mhetod.
all information about allertDialog is wery old.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.familyplaner1, PID: 20617
    **android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid;** is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:935)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:387)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:96)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:344)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1156)
        at com.example.familyplaner1.fragments.HomeFragment.noteCreateDialog(HomeFragment.kt:64)
        at com.example.familyplaner1.fragments.HomeFragment$init$1.onClick(HomeFragment.kt:40)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7160)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7137)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27418)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

```
 fun noteCreateDialog(view: View) {
        val appContext = requireContext().applicationContext
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(appContext)
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        builder.setTitle("edit text")
        val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_text, null)
        val editTextDialog = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text_dialog)
        builder.setView(dialogLayout)
        builder.show()
    }
```

Comment: Please show where you call this function from. You might have tried to open the dialog before the Fragment is attached to the Activity.

Comment: oh i am search a problem sorry, my problem in context in ```val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(appContext)```  instead appContext i take  a ```activit``` and all work